# How can I point a domain at a changing IP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dhcp

So I'm running a website off my own server. I piggybacked off my dad's domain; I added subdomain, evamsharma.finosus.com, and pointed to our network IP, and set up port forwarding. But when I logged onto it this morning, our IP had changed. It has stayed stable before, but I guess my ISP uses DHCP. Anyway, I need to know how to point my domain at my router even when the IP is changing. I looked at No-IP, but I couldn't figure out how to use it with my existing subdomain without transferring the domain registration to No-IP, which I couldn't do because my dad needs that domain.]

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up no-ip subdomain on your ip address, set up the dynamic DNS client and make sure it works then set up a *cname* record for `evamsharma.finosus.com` pointing at the no-ip subdomain.

Comment: No-IP seems only to have options for subdomains for a specific site that they own....if I wanted my domain to still show up in the address bar, how would I do that?

Comment: Thats why you set up a cname record - a cname record basically says "if there's any requests for evamsharma.finosus.net, send it over to somedomain.no-ip.com" - as such you need to basically replace the A record for evamsharma.finosus.net pointing at a IP address with a Cname record pointing at FQDN.

Comment: So what I'm doing is setting `evamsharma.finosus.com` to point to the No-IP IP. In turn, the No-IP IP points to my server, regardless of my network's changing public IP. Right?

Comment: It'll work until your ISP decides to block you.  I highly recommend you read your ISP's Acceptable Use Policy.  Caveat emptor.  Consider a cheap VPS or cloud provider if you are serious about having a web site.

Comment: Or block the port for that matter. I've been running my personal site on a VPS, so I kind of forgot about that